# SetFocus does not work on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, iphone, autofocus

We found that this code works on a PC with: IE, Safari and FireFox.
However on an iPad or iPhone with Safari it does not auto focus on a textbox.
We cannot touch the screen and click the textbox, we need the auto focus.
Any tips here?

thanks!

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
<!--
function SetFocus()
{
    document.form1['txtCode'].focus();
}
window.onload = SetFocus;
// -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it appears Mobile Safari does not support this behaviour, by design.

http://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari-iPhone-or-iPad-with-JavaScript-how-can-I-launch-the-on-screen-keyboard

Answer (score -3):

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('txtCode').focus();">
    <form>
        <input type="text" value="Text Here" name="txtCode" id="txtCode" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Try This

Comment: Nope, same issue
http://seminars.dmxtutorials.com/test.html?txtCode=Text+Heredsds