# how to set focus on input when after dropdown value is selected in web page

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, drop-down-menu, web

I have drop down i want that when user select any value from dropdown then set focus of the cursor in input field. But this should work on ipad also.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>formDemo.html</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form Demo</h1>
<form>
<legend>Selecting elements</legend>
<p>
 <label>Select list</label>
         <select id = "myList">
           <option value = "1">one</option>
           <option value = "2">two</option>
           <option value = "3">three</option>
           <option value = "4">four</option>
         </select>
      </p>

  <input type="text" name="txt1" > 


  <form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElemmentById("myList").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.querySelector("[name=txt1]").focus();
  } 
}
```

the focus my still not be possible in iOS or at least in mobile Safari because it will bring up the keypad and that is not necessarily what the user wants so Apple disabled to focus using a script. [SetFocus does not work on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118885/setfocus-does-not-work-on-ipad)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id = "myList" onchange="document.getElementsByName('txt1')[0].focus()">
```

Comment: sorry to tell but there is no "focus" function in safari 5-, which are ipad uses.